# CAMERA_MSG_ENV_DETECT 101058054

Tags: android, android-camera

I made a simple camera app by following this [Android camera api guide.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

Everything seems to be working just fine, except the fact that I'm getting an error `CAMERA_MSG_ENV_DETECT 101058054` in Logcat when the room is too dark or I make the area around the device camera too dark(put my hand on it, put the device on the desk...)

Here's my logcat:

```
11-09 21:44:38.477 19645-19645/com.cameratest V/CameraActivity: Camera already released and was null!
11-09 21:44:38.647 19645-19645/com.cameratest V/CameraActivity: Camera opened
11-09 21:44:38.684 19645-19645/com.cameratest V/CameraSurfaceView: Entered surfaceCreated block!
11-09 21:44:38.913 19645-19645/com.cameratest V/CameraSurfaceView: Entered surfaceChanged block!
11-09 21:44:44.865 19645-19645/com.cameratest E/Camera: CAMERA_MSG_ENV_DETECT 101058054
11-09 21:44:44.935 19645-19645/com.cameratest E/Camera: CAMERA_MSG_ENV_DETECT 101058054
11-09 21:44:45.006 19645-19645/com.cameratest E/Camera: CAMERA_MSG_ENV_DETECT 101058054
11-09 21:44:45.075 19645-19645/com.cameratest E/Camera: CAMERA_MSG_ENV_DETECT 101058054
11-09 21:44:45.144 19645-19645/com.cameratest E/Camera: CAMERA_MSG_ENV_DETECT 101058054
11-09 21:44:45.215 19645-19645/com.cameratest E/Camera: CAMERA_MSG_ENV_DETECT 101058054
```

**CameraActivity**

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
        private boolean isPreviewRunning;
        private Camera mCamera;
        private FrameLayout mPreviewFrame;
        private CameraSurfaceView mCameraSurfaceView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
            mPreviewFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreviewContainer);
        }

        // Call safelyOpenCamera() in onResume()
        // Call releaseCameraAndPreview() in onPause()

        private void safelyOpenCamera() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(() -> {
                    releaseCameraAndPreview();

                    mCamera = getDeviceCamera();
                    if(mCamera == null) 
                        Log.v(TAG, "Camera failed to open");

                    Log.v(TAG, "Camera opened");
                    mCameraSurfaceView = new CameraSurfaceView(getApplicationContext(), mCamera);
                    mPreviewFrame.addView(mCameraSurfaceView);
                    isPreviewRunning = true;
            });
        }

        private Camera getDeviceCamera(){
            Camera camera = null;
            try{
                camera = Camera.open();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return camera;
        }

        private void releaseCameraAndPreview(){
            if(mCamera == null)
                return;

            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            mPreviewFrame.removeView(mCameraSurfaceView);
            mCameraSurfaceView = null;
            isPreviewRunning = false;
            Log.v(TAG, "Camera released!");
        }
    }
```

**CameraSurfaceView**

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Entered surfaceCreated block!");
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Entered surfaceChanged block!");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Entered surfaceDestroyed block!");
    }
}
```

**Google** gave me **no (useful) results** and I double checked the guide and docs to see if I did everything right. I'm running it on Lenovo P2a42 with android 7.0.

How do I fix what's wrong or prevent it from taking over my logcat in case that's just normal behavior?

Comment: I have same errors on this phone, I think we should not worry about it, it's just something in Lenovo Android OS, ignore it